# Execute .sql file in psql, passing parameters from Excel cell values

Tags: sql, postgresql, excel, psql, vba

I'm trying to execute a .sql file in psql (through a .bat script), passing as parameters the values contained in cell **B1** and **B2** of **test.xlsm** workbook. I have been looking for a possible solution but I can't understand how I can refer to these values (cell B1 and B2 in Excel) in the .sql file.

This is what I've been working on so far.

The **download_from_postgresql.bat** file contains the following script, in order to establish a connection and run the download_view.sql file mention above through psql.exe:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set PGPASSWORD=mypassword
"D:\PostgreSQL\10\bin\psql.exe" -h myserver.com -U myuser -d mydb -f C:/QA_nepal/download_view.sql
endlocal
```

The **download_view.sql** file contains the following script in order to export a .csv file of a specific view created directly on the PostgreSQL server I'm connected to:

```
\copy (SELECT * FROM public_qa_stfc_india."join_tables_date_filter=custom_user_filter=none") to 'C:\\QA_nepal\\test.csv' with CSV HEADER;
\q
```

The **join_tables_date_filter=custom_user_filter=none** view, I'm referring to, is created directly on my PostgreSQL server and looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM public_qa_stfc_india.step_3_joined_tables
WHERE "left"(step_3_joined_tables._0_general_start, 10) >= '2018-05-03'::text
AND "left"(step_3_joined_tables._0_general_start, 10) <= '2018-05-04'::text;
```

What I'd like to do is edit the view definition included above, in order to have something like:

```
SELECT * FROM public_qa_stfc_india.step_3_joined_tables
WHERE "left"(step_3_joined_tables._0_general_start, 10) >= 'date_par_1'::text
AND "left"(step_3_joined_tables._0_general_start, 10) <= 'date_par_2'::text;
```

and pass the value of cell B1 to date_par_1 and the value of B2 to date_par_2. The Excel workbook I'm referring to is in C:\QA_nepal\excel\test.xlsm.

At this point I'm not sure on how to proceed. Should I instruct psql to read these values from Excel? And so add instructions in download_from_postgresql.bat? Or should I refer in some way to the values in Excel directly in the download_view.sql file?

Thanks in advance for any help,
Stefano

**UPDATE 2018/06/19**

I managed to write a macro in VB able to pass the values in cells B1 and B2 (the values are respectively 2018-01-01 and 2015-02-07) to the .bat file:

```
Sub batch()
Dim wsh As Object
Dim data_1 As String
Dim data_2 As String
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

data_1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio1").Range("B1").Value
data_2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio1").Range("B2").Value

wsh.Run "C:\QA_nepal\download_from_postgresql.bat " & data_1 & " " & data_2, windowStyle, waitOnReturn

End Sub
```

Now my **download_from_postgresql.bat** file looks like this:

```
@echo off
SET data_1=%1%
SET data_2=%2%
ECHO %data_1% 'test if the value in B1 is passed to the .bat file correctly
ECHO %data_2% 'test if the value in B2 is passed to the .bat file correctly
setlocal
set PGPASSWORD=mypassword
"D:\PostgreSQL\10\bin\psql.exe" -h myserver.com -U myuser -d mydb -v v1=%data_1% -v v2=%data_2% -f C:/QA_nepal/download_view.sql
endlocal
```

At this point, I'm not sure how I can refer to the variables **v1** and **v2** in the **download_view.sql**:

```
\copy (SELECT * FROM public_qa_stfc_india."join_tables_date_filter=custom_user_filter=none") to 'C:\\QA_nepal\\test.csv' with CSV HEADER;
\q
```

considering my **join_tables_date_filter=custom_user_filter=none** view looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM public_qa_stfc_india.step_3_joined_tables
WHERE "left"(step_3_joined_tables._0_general_start, 10) >= '2018-05-03'::text
AND "left"(step_3_joined_tables._0_general_start, 10) <= '2018-05-04'::text;
```

I know that I have to replace the dates ('2018-05-03' and '2018-05-04') in the view above with 2 variables (let's say var1 and var2) and then I have to "connect" these variables (var1 and var2) with the variables in the .bat file (v1 and v2) I tried in different ways, for instance having something like:

```
\copy (SELECT * FROM public_qa_stfc_india."join_tables_date_filter=custom_user_filter=none" WHERE var1 = (:v1) AND var2 = (:v2)) to 'C:\\QA_nepal\\test.csv' with CSV HEADER;
\q
```

and:

```
SELECT * FROM public_qa_stfc_india.step_3_joined_tables
WHERE "left"(step_3_joined_tables._0_general_start, 10) >= '$var1'::text
AND "left"(step_3_joined_tables._0_general_start, 10) <= '$var2'::text;
```

but with no success. I'm actually pretty new to SQL in general so I might be on a  vert wrong path. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Stefano

Comment: Why use a batch file if VBA is available? Simply call `psql` directly with shell. Plus, if you have the Postgres ODBC, you can have Excel query database directly and output to CSV.

Comment: Thanks Parfait for the comment, that's a good point. But in any case I should be able to replace '2018-05-03' and '2018-05-04' with variables in my **join_tables_date_filter=custom_user_filter=none** view (the view is already created in PgAdmin4), isn't it? And then "link" these variables to the ones in the VB macro (data_1 and data_2). I tried in different ways I cannot find the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing your stored view which hard codes dates and receives no parameters with a function to receive parameters and runs the `COPY` command with [string format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html). Then have `psql` call the function.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_date_filter_func(start_dt TEXT, end_dt TEXT, csv_file TEXT)
    RETURNS void AS 
$func$
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('COPY (SELECT * FROM public_qa_stfc_india.step_3_joined_tables s
                          WHERE LEFT(s._0_general_start, 10) >= %L
                            AND LEFT(s._0_general_start, 10) <= %L) TO %L with CSV HEADER;', 
                   start_dt, end_dt, csv_file);
  END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**psql** command via **VBA** shell call

```vb
...
path = "C:/QA_nepal/test.csv"
cmd_str = "psql ... -c ""SELECT my_date_filter_func('" & data_1 & "', '" & data_2 & "', '" & path & "')"""

wsh.Run cmd_str, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

Finally, it is unclear why you are treating date fields as text with `LEFT()` as you can use date literals directly in `WHERE` clause with timestamp implicitly defined for midnight: `00:00:00`.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM public_qa_stfc_india.step_3_joined_tables s
WHERE s._0_general_start >= '2018-05-03'
  AND s._0_general_start <= '2018-05-04';
```